# how to set condition parameter with find attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am new in ROR

i want to set `condition` parameter with `find` attribute.

See below my code

```
@navmenu = MenuItem.find(:all,:conditions=>[MenuItem.menu_item_id == nil OR MenuItem.id != 1 AND MenuItem.is_active == 1] )
```

this query given error. Please help

Comment: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== nil OR MenuItem.id != 1 AND MenuItem.is

Comment: Read the docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will helps you:

@navmenu = MenuItem.find(:all,:conditions=>["menu_items.menu_item_id = ? OR menu_items.id <> ?  AND menu_items.is_active = ?", nil, 1, true])

Thanks.